# Can I use the ternary operator with two functions each returning void?

Tags: c#, if-statement, methods, inline, void

In C# is possible to use an if inline condition with no value, in other words returning `void`?

```
public void FuncReturningVoid ()
{
    return;
}

public void AnotherFuncReturningVoid()
{
    return;
}

public void Test ()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    // I whish I could to do this:
    a == b ? FuncReturningVoid() : AnotherFuncReturningVoid();

    //would be the same...
    if (a == b)
    {
        FuncReturningVoid();
    }
    else
    {
        AnotherFuncReturningVoid();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you can't use the conditional operator like that. I'm sure this is a dupe - trying to find one now.

Comment: The terms of my search doesn't matched with this, thanks for all :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Not possible. This are the compilation errors:

- Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
- Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'void' and 'void'